# Dangers of @ComponentScan'ing all packages with filters

Tags: spring

I am working on a concept application right now where I want to use component scanning to pick up ALL classes anywhere on the classpath with a certain custom Spring meta-annotation.  My annotation looks like:

```
@Target(value=ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
public @interface PluggableController {
    String value(); // Allows for the setting of the @Controller bean name
}
```

And in my ApplConfig class I have:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"**"}, includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=PluggableController.class)})
```

The idea being that users will create a controller using my custom @Controller, which will automagically be picked up by Spring and handled like any other Spring controller.  However, I don't want to force people to use a rigid classpath structure.

I am well aware of the dangers of scanning all classpaths (speed of startup, picking up bad dependencies, etc), but the question is am I mitigating those dangers by limiting/filtering to that particular annotation?  I am not overly concerned with startup speed, mostly concerned with running into issues I hadn't anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

You wont mitigate those dangers by limiting/filtering to that particular annotation.
Spring will scan all classes of all jars in the classpath and check each for your annotation.

Most plugin systems require you to put the plugin code into a well defined location, so I would strongly suggest to just do the same here.